# Shiny Application, Download button for graphs

Tags: r

Goodnight

I'm making an application in shiny, and it goes perfectly, try to adjust a variable according to gammls families, the application puts a graph the first four variables. The only problem is that when I want to create a button to download the graphic, I could not do it

Attach the server and the wm

And I really appreciate the help

```
Server
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
  observe({
    inFile<-input$file1
    #print(inFile)
    if(is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    dt = read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep)
    updateSelectInput(session, "product", choices = names(dt))
    updateSelectInput(session, "familia", choices = c("realAll","realline","realplus","real0to1","counts","binom"))
  })
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    require(gamlss)
    inFile<-input$file1
    dt = read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep)
    k<-input$k
    m <- fitDist(dt[,input$product], type=input$familia, k=k)
    par(mfrow=c(2, 2))
    for (i in 1:4) {
      denst <- density(dt[,input$product])
      res <- histDist(dt[,input$product], family=names(m$fits)[i],
                      main=names(m$fits)[i],
                      xlab=input$product,
                      line.wd=3,
                      line.ty=1,
                      line.col='dodgerblue2',
                      ylim=c(0, 1.3 * max(denst$y)))
      param <- c('mu', 'sigma', 'nu', 'tau') 
      np <- length(res$parameters) 
      fun1 <- function(x) eval(parse(text=x))
      hat.param <- sapply(as.list(paste('res$', param[1:np], sep='')),
                          fun1)
      hat.param <- round(hat.param, digits=2)
      txt <- paste('hat(', param[1:np], ')==', hat.param, sep='')
      txt <- paste(txt, collapse=', ')
      legend('topright', bty='n',
             legend=eval(parse(text=paste('expression(', txt, ')'))))
    }
  })
  output$descarga<-downloadHandler(
    filename=function(){
      paste("grafica","png",sep=".")
    },content=function(file){
      png(file)
      plotOutput("distPlot")
      dev.off() 
     }
    )

})
```

UI

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel( "Mejor Ajuste de Distribución para una variable", "Flowserve"),
  sidebarPanel(
    h5('Esta aplicacion sirve para mostrar las cuatro mejores distribuciones
       que ajustan a una variable elegida de una base de datos'),
    br(),
    fileInput('file1', 'Use el boton siguiente para cargar la base de datos.',
              accept = c(
                'text/csv',
                'text/comma-separated-values',
                'text/tab-separated-values',
                'text/plain',
                '.csv',
                '.tsv'
              )
    ),
    checkboxInput('header', 'Tiene encabezado la base de datos?', TRUE),
    radioButtons('sep', 'Cual es la separacion de sus datos?',
                 c(Tab='\t', Comma=',', Semicolon=';' )
    ),
    tags$hr(),
    selectInput("product", "Seleccione la variable de la base de datos",""),
    selectInput("familia", "Seleccione la familia de distribuciones, realAll son todas
                las distribuciones reales, realline son todas las distribuciones reales lineales, 
                realPlus son todas las distribuciones reales positivas, real0to1 son las distribuciones
                reales de 0 a 1, counts son las distribuciones de conteo, binom son tipos de distribuciones
                binomiales",""),
    numericInput(inputId="k",
                 label="Ingrese una penalización de cantidad de parametros entre mayor sea el k mayor la penalizacion",
                 min=1,
                 value=4,
                 step=1) 
    ),
  mainPanel(h4('A continuacion el ajuste para la variable seleccionada por 
               el usuario'),
            plotOutput("distPlot"),downloadButton(outputId="descarga",'Descargar'))
    ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

**server.R:**

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
  observe({
    inFile<-input$file1
    #print(inFile)
    if(is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    dt = read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep)
    updateSelectInput(session, "product", choices = names(dt))
    updateSelectInput(session, "familia", choices = c("realAll","realline","realplus","real0to1","counts","binom"))
  })
  testplot <- function(){
    require(gamlss)
    inFile<-input$file1
    dt = read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep)
    k<-input$k
    m <- fitDist(dt[,input$product], type=input$familia, k=k)
    par(mfrow=c(2, 2))
    for (i in 1:4) {
      denst <- density(dt[,input$product])
      res <- histDist(dt[,input$product], family=names(m$fits)[i],
                      main=names(m$fits)[i],
                      xlab=input$product,
                      line.wd=3,
                      line.ty=1,
                      line.col='dodgerblue2',
                      ylim=c(0, 1.3 * max(denst$y)))
      param <- c('mu', 'sigma', 'nu', 'tau') 
      np <- length(res$parameters) 
      fun1 <- function(x) eval(parse(text=x))
      hat.param <- sapply(as.list(paste('res$', param[1:np], sep='')),
                          fun1)
      hat.param <- round(hat.param, digits=2)
      txt <- paste('hat(', param[1:np], ')==', hat.param, sep='')
      txt <- paste(txt, collapse=', ')
      legend('topright', bty='n',
             legend=eval(parse(text=paste('expression(', txt, ')'))))
    }
  }

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({testplot()})

  output$descarga<-downloadHandler(
    filename=function(){
      paste("grafica","png",sep=".")
    },content=function(file){
      png(file)
      print(testplot())
      dev.off() 
    }
  )

})
```

I wrapped Your code inside of the function (`testplot()`) which i have further used to `renderPlot` and inside of `downloadHandler`.

*For the future it would be better if you give/attach sample data, so Your code could be easily run in `R`